# In Exchange 2013, what is the meaning of "NotApplicable" State when one runs a get-healthreport?

Tags: exchange-2013

I am a new exchange admin and as I am review my inherited environment, I am trying to make sense of it.

This environment is made of 2 Exchange 2013 SP1 with DAG and 4 DB (2 active, 2 passive)

All is working fine but the result of the Health commands in Exchange puzzles me.

Specifically I am looking at the output of this:

```
[PS] D:\Exchange Server\V15\Scripts>Get-ServerHealth exchange1| more

Server          State           Name                 TargetResource       HealthSetName   AlertValue ServerComp
                                                                                                     onent
------          -----           ----                 --------------       -------------   ---------- ----------
exchange1    NotApplicable   ActiveSyncCTPMonitor ActiveSync           ActiveSync      Healthy    None
exchange1    NotApplicable   ActiveSyncSelfTes... MSExchangeSyncApp... ActiveSync.P... Healthy    None
exchange1    NotApplicable   RequestsQueuedGt5... MSExchangeSyncApp... ActiveSync      Healthy    None
exchange1    Online          OutlookProxyTestM... MSExchangeRpcProx... Outlook.Proxy   Unhealthy  RpcProxy
exchange1    NotApplicable   AutodiscoverSelfT... MSExchangeAutoDis... Autodiscover... Healthy    None
exchange1    Online          AutodiscoverProxy... MSExchangeAutodis... Autodiscover... Unhealthy  AutoDis...
exchange1    Online          ActiveSyncProxyTe... MSExchangeSyncApp... ActiveSync.P... Unhealthy  ActiveS...
exchange1    Offline         OABProxyTestMonitor  MSExchangeOABAppPool OAB.Proxy       Unhealthy  OabProxy
exchange1    Online          RWSProxyTestMonitor  MSExchangeReporti... RWS.Proxy       Healthy    RwsProxy
```

When I look at this I am worried as healthsets are unhealthy. I assume that most worrisome  would be the online sets that are unhealthy and can understand this.

What I am unsure of is the state of "NotApplicable" ? Does it mean I should not care? I am very confused.

Comment: FYI - I could not find anything on MSFT source as per the NotApplicable, this is still a mystery. However, as pointed out some unhealthly components are due to corrupted Health Monitor mailboxes/users which I had to delete and restore the Exchange Health Service in order for them to be recreated. I believe  SP1 would have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column you should be worried about is to the right - where it says Unhealthy. That suggests a problem. There is nothing official about the "NonApplicable" state, so ignore it.

If the environment is still at SP1, then I would update it to begin with. That resolves a lot issues. Exchange 2013 was still in active development until recently, so a lot of issues were resolved in later updates.